# Service Worker only updates page with developer tools active

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, debugging, service-worker, fetch-api

Lately I'm doing more with Service Workers and build a small script that checks if you are offline so I can serve out my own custom "offline page" to the user. Today I discovered that with my developer tools closed (Chrome 61+) the page is not being updated with my latest modifications to the page when developing my website further (HTML, CSS and JavaScript). It seems to be related to my Service Worker script.

If I uninstall the SW or remove all code in the file I do see my changes with my developer tools deactivated. I pinned down the problem to the fetch method that I'm using as a callback of `event.respondWith`. But this is also where I get stuck.

All the help is very much appreciated!

Thanks in advance,
Stefan

```js
"use strict";

// Install stage sets up the offline page in the cache and opens a new cache.
self.addEventListener('install', function(event){

 let offlinePage = new Request('Offline.html');

 event.waitUntil(

  fetch(offlinePage).then(function(response){

   return caches.open('page-offline').then(function(cache){

    console.log('Cached offline page during install', response.url);
    return cache.put(offlinePage, response);
   });
  })
 );
});

// If any fetch fails, it will show the offline page.
self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event){

 event.respondWith(

  fetch(event.request).catch(function(error){

    console.error('Network request failed, serving the offline page: ' + error);

    return caches.open('page-offline').then(function(cache){

     return cache.match('Offline.html');
    });
   }
  })
});
```

Comment: "the page is not being updated with my latest modifications" => which page? the Offline.html file?

Comment: Sorry for the unclarity. No I am talking about the website page(s) itself. So the page the Service Worker runs on :)

Comment: Ok, then it looks more like your browser has cached the webpage itself and not the service worker. Did you already checked: https://superuser.com/questions/220179/how-can-i-do-a-cache-refresh-in-google-chrome

Comment: Indeed, looks very much like it... Your suggestion did not solve it unfortunately. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Any luck finding a solution for this? I am also facing the same issue - i.e, my service worker 'fetch' call happens only if I open the developer window and not otherwise. Have you found a solution for this?